# Ubuntu installer is blank (can't select partition)

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, virtualbox

As of now, I am able to run Ubuntu Unity through VirtualBox. Now, I want to install Ubuntu to a partition, which I have already created AND formatted. However, in VirtualBox, when I click 'install Ubuntu', at step 4/7, the block which should list partitions (with header 'Device Type Mount point etc.' is completely blank.

I have no idea what I have to do next. Why is nothing listed there? If I simply click install now, it says

`No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.`

I want to, but I can't... has anyone experienced this before? I run Linux through a LiveUSB, the Linux version is 64bit. No problems when booting in VirtualBox, everything is possible inside it.

If you need more information, I'll gladly give it to you :D

Comment: We have some restrictions for new (=low-reputation) users, because our site is often threatened by spammers and other evil people and/or bots. So you have to prove that you are real and willing to let both you and our site profit from your visits here. And this site is not controlled by some paid moderators but by the community itself. Therefore we have this reputation system: The more you improve the site by posting good questions and answers (etc), the higher your rep will rise and the more privileges you will get. To your screenshot: Give us any link and we will include it to your question.

Comment: But it's a screenshot :( it's a file on my computer, not a file online, sadly. But never mind, I think readers will understand what I mean.

Comment: You can just visit http://imgur.com/ and click on "Upload image" without registration. Then insert the link into your question and I will edit it from a simple link to an embedded image. You will be able to do that yourself as soon as you have 10 points. Btw imgur.com is the image host used everywhere on AU. Whenever you upload an image on AU or another StackExchange website, it will be saved there.

Comment: Great! Will do that in the future :D By the way, any suggestions for my problem?

Comment: Erm... You are installing Ubuntu _inside_ VirtualBox, but on a physical partition? That sounds weird - or did I just not get you right?

Comment: Inside virtualbox, I click on 'Install', and then I get the empty page. I want to install it to a partition, though (as in: a partition on my laptops's hard drive).

Comment: But run it inside the VM you have installed on Windows (I assume), or run as real operating system your machine can boot? And why don't you upload the screenshot now as you know how to do so?

Comment: IF you want to install Ubuntu inside VirtualBox, the easier way is to create a Virtual Hard Disk and install to it (VBox should guide you to install that way). Installing to a real partition from Virtual Box is possible, but it's more complicated and it's only useful for a handful of cases that are usually associated with servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)  as it's impossible to install Ubuntu from within a virtualbox onto a partition managed by its host system...  ;-)